# COUNTRSTRIKE GO config & skins

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, macos

While it's been many years since I played Counter-Strike I have recently purchased CS GO, and want to know a few things.

1 - what is the DIR and filename of the player config on OSX?

2 - are custom skins still something that is doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just break your question up:

---

> What is the DIR and filename of the player config on OSX?

This varies depending on your Steam setup and folder location, but by default, it should be in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive
```

... which puts it in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/cfg
```

---

> Are custom skins still something that is doable?

Depends on your definition of 'custom skins', custom *modded* skins are only possible on third-party servers (and is deemed 'illegal' by Valve).
This is due to skins [in CS:GO] being an economical item, which can be created by submitting to their curated workshop to be <s>'sold' or</s> placed in crates, and obtained (in-game) by unlocking it through a crate (and purchased key), via the community market or from drops.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid careful with the capital letters.

Comment: I read somewhere that the player config is not in that dir unless you make oneconfig.cfg - Is this correct? @aytimothy

Comment: No. It creates one when you start the game for the first time.

Comment: hmm, that wasn't the case for me. I opened the game twice now with no such file in there. You're saying config.cfg will be in that folder on its own ? @aytimothy

Comment: Why is this post getting so many downvotes?